# Forgot my Windows 7 Password, but can still login with my finger

Tags: windows-7

I login with my finger scan reader all the time, so I forgot my password. How can I remove it or change it? I am on Windows 7 64bit

Comment: Just don't forget your finger... :-)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can set the password through the command prompt without knowing the previous password. Here's how:

1. Open an administrative command prompt (Right-click Command Prompt and Run as Administrator).
2. Type `set username` in the command prompt. You will see your username (useful if you don't know what it is from the OEM, etc.)
3. Type `net user username *` (replace username with the username from step 2.
4. Type in your new password and press enter. You won't see any stars or anything as you're typing - but it is typing! If you mess up you can press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> to cancel or press <kbd>Backspace</kbd> enough times to delete what you've typed. If you cancel, just type in the command from step 3 again.
5. Type in the same password again and press enter.

If it worked you should see `The command completed successfully.`

Answer (score 2):

Check [this link](http://www.askstudent.com/hacking/how-to-change-your-windows-password-using-the-command-line/), you can do this using the `NET USER` command at a command prompt. You will probably need to open your command prompt with **Run As Administrator** enabled.